# Tagged search no longer works after joining a Team

Tags: bug, tags, stack-overflow-for-teams, search-box

Yesterday I joined my first Team only to discover that tagged search no longer works. This is true whether I search the public site or my Team site.

For example, I used to be able to search for `[python]` to go right to the "Questions tagged [python]" page (`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python`). This still works in an incognito window, but when I'm logged in such a search goes instead to "Search Results in Public" (`https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[python]&mixed=0`).

The old `/questions/tagged/python` URL works when I type it in manually or navigate to `/tags` and click on [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python).

Is this change deliberate?